WeWork chapter 11 bankruptcy. Can an offer better than the creditors offer be rejected?
WeWork is going through Chapter 11. Currently, they seem to be going with the offer from the creditors. However, Adam Neumann has offered them more money than than the creditors. He initially offered the money prior to them filing for bankruptcy.
It sounds like as a publicity stunt he's trying to bailout the shareholders to improve his image. His new venture will take over the company, and starts paying the debt. He's fairly well financed.
Is WeWork allowed to reject his offer?

Its not WeWork or the shareholder's decision to make. When a company goes into Chapter 11, the shareholders hand over fiduciary possession to the creditors of the company. As such, it is the creditors decision as to whether they think the existing offer or Adam Neumann's offer is more likely to get them more of the debts re-payed.

What about the fact WeWork turned down his offer prior to filing for chapter 11, and did not act in the best interests of the shareholders?

That's something for weworks shareholders to dispute with the board, and not relevant any more.

If it could be proven that the board acted against their fiduciary duties to the shareholders, then the shareholders could sue them for resulting damages. But it would be hard to argue that they weren't doing what they thought was in the best interests of the shareholders at the time.

@user1937198 Not hard - impossible given the "business judgement" rule in evaluating board decisions.

What is the "business judgement" rule? Would that be protect them from turning down a $1 billion bailout. Does it even matter since SoftBank owns the majority of shares?

@ZeroPhase Its that boards don't have to make good decisions. They are presumed to have made their best effort to choose the correct decision in the absence of evidence that they are actively attempting to defraud the shareholders. So under the business judgement rule, all of the context around the deal and whether it would have made sense is irrelevant. You would need to find evidence a board member was making decisions based on an illegal reasoning like conflict of interest or explicitly trying to reduce the value of the company.
